# Can I use jq for using parameters from a JSON file to filter and modify another JSON file?

Tags: json, file, parameters, jq

Let's say I have two input JSON files. The first one is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "one",
        "keyB": "2",
        "keyC": "3"
    },
    {
        "name": "two",
        "keyB": "15",
        "keyC": "20"
    }
]
```

And the second one:

```
{
    "name": "one",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "0",
            "valueB" : "0"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "11",
            "valueB": "21"
        },
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "21",
            "valueB": "30"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "1",
            "valueB": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "2",
            "valueB": "3"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "5",
            "valueB": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to create a logic that when `.[].name` from the first file is equals to `.features[].name` from the second file I concatenate its corresponding keys from the first file on the second file (considering that the value of `.[].name` on the first file is always unique). So the result would be the following:

```
{
    "name": "one",
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "0",
            "valueB" : "0",
            "keyB": "2",
            "keyC": "3"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "11",
            "valueB": "21",
            "keyB": "15",
            "keyC": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "21",
            "valueB": "30",
            "keyB": "2",
            "keyC": "3"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "1",
            "valueB": "2",
            "keyB": "15",
            "keyC": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "one",
            "valueA": "2",
            "valueB": "3",
            "keyB": "2",
            "keyC": "3"
        },  
        {
            "name": "two",
            "valueA": "5",
            "valueB": "3",
            "keyB": "15",
            "keyC": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this output, I just checked where the `name` is equal on both JSON files and then I brought the keys `keyB: "2", "keyC": "3"` where `name == "one"` and `keyB: "15", "keyC": "20"` where `name == "two"`. Is it possible to do with jq? Can I work with two JSON files in a way that I get parameters from one file to give it to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just save the first one in a variable.

```
INDEX(.name) as $p | inputs | .features |= map($p[.name] + .)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2MiSs1EjGN)</sup>

Comment: Just as a curiosity... Would it be easy to adapt this line to the case where I want to have two variables to monitor instead of just one (`name`)? Let's say I have `name` and `type` and they both need to be equal (name equals to name and type equals to type)... Can I there anything like `INDEX(.name&.type) as $p | inputs | .features |= map($p[.name&.type] + .)` that could be done? (this sample is completely wrong, I just wanted to show the idea here)

Comment: @raylight No, I think we'd use a different approach for that. Sounds interesting though, consider asking it as a separate question.